# How to track the Http Protocol on the Server

Tags: sharepoint, iis

We do have many client specific tools (i.e. Httpwatch, Wfetch...) to track the Http Protocol however I want to track http protocol (headers) on the server end.

Please let me know if we have any tool to do this on the server end.

Answer (score 0):

[WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is my favorite tool to do that. CLIENT and/or SERVER side. Is't free, very useful, used with many (not only HTTP) protocols and multiplatform.

Answer (score 0):

WireShark is good tool, but if you love command line give [tcpdump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcpdump) a try